# How to retrieve the the object which is represented by a Bar in Bar Graph in recharts (recharts.org) on an onClick event on that particular bar?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, bar-chart, recharts

I am working on a project in which, I have converted my data object array into a bar graph using recharts library for react js.
Lets say my object array is as follows:
[
{
"AppName" : "abc",
"count" : 1
},
{
"AppName" : "abc1",
"count" : 2
},
{
"AppName" : "abc2",
"count" : 3
},
]

This object array has been converted into a bar graph having 3 different bars for the three objects "abc", "abc1", "abc2" and the height of the bars represents the count attribute in each object.

Now if I click on a particular bar, I need the value of the "AppName" attribute of the bar. Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Here is how a bar graph is made using recharts library: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleBarChart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the link you sent. Add this to the bar element

```
                   // logs all the details of the bar
<Bar onClick={(data)=> { console.log(data) }} dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8"/>
```

Comment: Working example if I understood your question correctly : https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-bar-chart-forked-isgbxy?file=/src/App.tsx